# Qbittorrent moving files before they're completed

Tags: download, qbittorrent

I've got qbittorrent set up so incomplete downloads are in one folder and they move to a completed folder when finished downloading.

What Ive noticed recently is there were many more files in the completed folder than were showing as completed on qbt.

I did some manual checking and there were multiple files which were in both the completed and incomplete folders and were still showing as downloading.

I closed qbt down completely and then moved the incomplete files out of the completed folder then restarted qbt.

They were all showing as not being able to find the files, so I did a force recheck and they all started again from 0%.

Gradually as they STARTED downloading they appeared in the completed folder again.

Ive reapplied my folder setting in the main options and in the right click menu torrent options to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this? Its not all files just the odd few, and I can't see a correlation between the ones it does and doesn't do it for

Comment: Some oddities I've found, which might not apply to your issue: 1. L o o n g  filenames show as *incomplete*; downloading to a folder with short path helps (e.g., C:\tmp) 2. Are you allowing simultaneous *upload* from torrents? That might be an issue.